# How can I merge output from cat with existing file using sort command?

Tags: bash

I currently have two files: `anotherFile` and `myFile`, which is being merged together to a `result` file, which is sorted. All this is 3 steps, however I want to be able to make it to a so called "one-liner"

Currently

```bash
#(script which creates 'anotherFile')
anotherFile > result
cat ./myFile | cut -f 1,2 >> result
sort -o result{,}
```

I want to be able to "one-liner" this, so I don't have to refer to `result` file 3 times!

```
cat ./myFile | cut -f 1,2 | xargs -I sort -m anotherFile {} > finalFile
```

I know the following above will not work since the `{}` is not an existing file.

Comment: In your first code question, `anotherFile` is the name of a **program**, since you use it as `anotherFile > result`. The **output** of `anotherFile` becomes part of the result. In your attempt of an one-liner, the file `anotherFile` **itself** becomes part of the result. It's unclear to me what you intend here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{}` to run your commands in a group, then pipe the output of that group through `sort` and redirect it into a file:

```
{
  ./anotherFileScript
  cut -f 1,2 ./myFile
} | sort > finalFile
```

If you must have it on a single line, you need some semicolons:

```
{ ./anotherFileScript; cut -f 1,2 ./myFile; } | sort > finalFile
```

Because `cut` can read from a file, you can eliminate the needless `cat` as well.

Comment: I'll accept your answer @Thomas since you were first one. Thank you for making me feel stupid and also learning something new ! :)

However I should've changed by post, since I'm using the file which `./anotherFileScript` is making, so I have to use cat.

Comment: Shell syntax does that to people ;)

Comment: Forgot to specify the script `anotherFileScript` does create the `anotherFile`, and I can not use the output from `anotherFileScript` as input to my `finalFile`
final `{ cat anotherFile; cut -f 1,2 ./myFile; } | sort >finalFile`

Answer (score 2):

Each file is referenced once:

```
{ ./anotherFileScript; cut -f1,2 myfile; } | sort > result
```